# Get IP of connected client in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, python-sockets

is there a way to get the IP of the connected client? (And if possible the port it uses). 
I tried `client_socket.getsockname()` but it gave me my IP address.

Comment: [`getpeername()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername)

Comment: @spectras thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `socket.getpeername()` method.